# Rvest R not getting inner table

Tags: html, r, xpath, rvest, magrittr

I'm trying to retrieve the Medals Table inside Wikipedia for Olympics 2012.

```
library(rvest) 
library(magrittr)
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_at_the_2012_Summer_Olympics" 

    xpath0 <- '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[1]'
    xpath1 <- '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[2]'
    xpath2 <- '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]'
    xpath3 <- '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table'

    tb <- url %>%
      html() %>%
      html_nodes(xpath=xpath0) %>%
      html_nodes("") %>%
      html_table()
```

xpath0 or xpath1 return an error

```
Error in parse_simple_selector(stream) : 
  Expected selector, got <EOF at 1>
```

xpath2 and xpath3 return empty lists.

At same time I tried to use Selectorgadget (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/vignettes/selectorgadget.html) to point to the exact element. I got

> //td[(((count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1) = 1) and parent::*)] |
>   //*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ",
>   "headerSortDown", " " ))]

and the Error

Error in parse_simple_selector(stream) : 
  Expected selector, got

I really appreciate any help.

Joa

Comment: The table I want is "Medalists",  the one where the headers have  Medal Name Sport Event Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first table with the names has a complicated structure and seems to be very difficult to convert into a standard format. At least I didn't succeed.

A summary of the number of medals by sport and the total medals can be obtained with

```
library(rvest) #v.0.2.0.9000
url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_at_the_2012_Summer_Olympics" 
tb <- read_html(url) %>% html_node("table.wikitable:nth-child(2)") %>% html_table(fill=TRUE)
#> head(tb)
#   Medals by sport   NA   NA   NA    NA NA NA
#1            Sport 01 ! 02 ! 03 ! Total NA NA
#2         Swimming   16    9    6    31 NA NA
#3    Track & field    9   12    7    28 NA NA
#4       Gymnastics    3    1    2     6 NA NA
#5         Shooting    3    0    1     4 NA NA
#6           Tennis    3    0    1     4 NA NA
```

Then there is another table summarizing all competitors that you can get with

```
tb2 <- read_html(url) %>% html_node("table.wikitable:nth-child(20)") %>% html_table()
#> head(tb2)
#                        Sport Men Women Total
#1                     Archery   3     3     6
#2 Athletics (track and field)  63    62   125
#3                   Badminton   2     1     3
#4                  Basketball  12    12    24
#5                      Boxing   9     3    12
#6                    Canoeing   5     2     7
```

And this is the table of multiple medalists:

```
tb3 <- read_html(url) %>%  html_node("table.wikitable:nth-child(8)") %>% html_table(fill=TRUE)
#> head(tb3)
#  Multiple medalists            NA   NA   NA   NA    NA NA
#1               Name         Sport 01 ! 02 ! 03 ! Total NA
#2     Michael Phelps      Swimming    4    2    0     6 NA
#3     Missy Franklin      Swimming    4    0    1     5 NA
#4    Allison Schmitt      Swimming    3    1    1     5 NA
#5        Ryan Lochte      Swimming    2    2    1     5 NA
#6      Allyson Felix Track & field    3    0    0     3 NA
```

It really depends on which table you want to have, as pointed out by @Metrics. There are many tables on that page.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. The table I want is Medalists the one where the headers have  Medal Name Sport Event Date.

Comment: read_html() is the current html()? When I try your example I get the message > Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "read_html"

Comment: I got it working here with this version of your solution t  <- html(url)
t %>%  html_node("table.wikitable:nth-child(1)") %>% html_table(fill=T)  but child(1) brings 3 tables and the I want is the second child.

Comment: Hi! I indicated the version of `rvest` that I'm using, v0.2.0.9000, which I believe is the most recent one. That version recommends using `read_html()` instead of `html()`. I never noticed a difference between the two, though. Unfortunately, child(1) is just the complicated table that I mentioned in the beginning which I couldn't transform into a suitable format. If I manage to make some progress I'll update the post.

Comment: How do you locate the child number?

Comment: @PierreLafortune How did you find this old post? jw

Comment: Searching "rvest selector" questions. I posted in GMT also

Comment: Having a big headache getting tables from wikipedia. Like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_De_Niro_filmography

Comment: @PierreLafortune Which table do you need? Can you ping me in GMT? I haven't been there for a while so I would have to search the room...